# What is a "mysql client"?

Tags: mysql

Ok, this might be a very stupid question, but please, explain what does `mysql client` mean?

For example a PHP file, which connects to a MySQL database, is this a `mysql client`?

or PHPMyAdmin, is this also a `mysql client`?

Comment: uhmm sort of stupid `:D` peace! here [List of MySQL Client Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/programs-client.html)

Comment: this have nothing to do with mysql, this is same as with all other client-server applications. If you dont know about it, google still works (i checked) :)

Comment: The young geek / nerd generation doesn't take any pleasure in reading manuals / books, and only feeds on answers to specific cases, from the beginning. The only way for them to get over this recurring mistake inherent to our over-connected times would be to be deprived from internet for a few months, and left with nothing but references books about networking, compilers, design patterns.

Comment: The *client* is a reference to customer. A client is someone asking for a service. Therefore, in IT - anything that ASKS for something is a client. A browser is a client, mysqldump program is a client (if used), phpmyadmin is a client etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL client is something that connects to a database and does smth with it. E.g. you have a php code which connects to a database and retrieves information about users. So technically this code is a client because it creates mysql queries.